# Low frequencies burning out console channels?

Tags: analog, live-sound, bass, console

I am currently doing sound at a house show venue where a very nice live sound professional has left some of his very expensive equipment. Using his setup exactly as is, I ran the kick drum mic through channel 1 and a bass mic through channel 4. Lo and behold, channels 1 and 4 stopped working. Today I am running the kick through channel 9 and the bass through channel 12. Channel 12 stopped working.
What the hell is going on?

Comment: What’s the make and model of the mixer? How long does it take for a channel to stop working? Are you using any inserts on those channels? When a channel stops working, what exactly happens? Just no audio at all on that channel?

Comment: Do you talk about bass drum or connecting directly to bass amplifier of electrical bass. My guess is that if it is a bass amplifier you need a DI box. Otherwise, if the mics destroy the mixer inputs my first guess would be that there is major wiring fault on stage, possibly ground fault.